# Top-level window size

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapi, .net-4.0

> 1. Why is the minimum size of a top-level window constrained to **2x2** pixels?
> 2. Is it possible to override this constraint so that I can set the width/height to **< 2**.

If you run the sample application and change the size of the window to let's say `1,1` you'll see that the size is constrained to `2,2`.

[image: Application]

**Sample application**

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.wnd = New Window With {.BackColor = Color.Red, .Bounds = New Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200)}
        Me.grid = New PropertyGrid With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .SelectedObject = Me.wnd, .TabIndex = 1}
        Me.btn = New Button With {.Text = "Set {width=1, height=1} using SetWindowPos.", .Dock = DockStyle.Top, .Height = 30, .TabIndex = 0}
        Me.Controls.AddRange({Me.grid, Me.btn})
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleDisposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed
        If (Not Me.grid Is Nothing) Then Me.grid.Dispose()
        If (Not Me.wnd Is Nothing) Then Me.wnd.Dispose()
        If (Not Me.btn Is Nothing) Then Me.btn.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
        Window.SetWindowPos(New HandleRef(Me.wnd, Me.wnd.Handle), Nothing, 0, 0, 1, 1, (Window.SWP_DRAWFRAME Or Window.SWP_NOMOVE Or Window.SWP_NOZORDER Or Window.SWP_NOOWNERZORDER))
        Me.grid.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents wnd As Window
    Private WithEvents grid As PropertyGrid
    Private WithEvents btn As Button

    Public Class Window
        Inherits Control

        Public Sub New()
            Me.SetTopLevel(True)
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As System.EventArgs)
            Try
                If (IntPtr.Size = 4) Then
                    Dim style As Int32 = (GetWindowLong32(New HandleRef(Me, Me.Handle), GWL_STYLE) And Not (WS_CAPTION Or WS_THICKFRAME Or WS_MINIMIZE Or WS_MAXIMIZE Or WS_SYSMENU))
                    Dim exstyle As Int32 = (GetWindowLong32(New HandleRef(Me, Me.Handle), GWL_EXSTYLE) And Not (WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME Or WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE Or WS_EX_STATICEDGE))
                    SetWindowLong32(New HandleRef(Me, Me.Handle), GWL_STYLE, New HandleRef(Nothing, New IntPtr(style)))
                    SetWindowLong32(New HandleRef(Me, Me.Handle), GWL_EXSTYLE, New HandleRef(Nothing, New IntPtr(exstyle)))
                Else
                    Dim style As Int64 = (GetWindowLong64(New HandleRef(Me, Me.Handle), GWL_STYLE) And Not CLng(WS_CAPTION Or WS_THICKFRAME Or WS_MINIMIZE Or WS_MAXIMIZE Or WS_SYSMENU))
                    Dim exstyle As Int64 = (GetWindowLong64(New HandleRef(Me, Me.Handle), GWL_EXSTYLE) And Not CLng(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME Or WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE Or WS_EX_STATICEDGE))
                    SetWindowLong64(New HandleRef(Me, Me.Handle), GWL_STYLE, New HandleRef(Nothing, New IntPtr(style)))
                    SetWindowLong64(New HandleRef(Me, Me.Handle), GWL_EXSTYLE, New HandleRef(Nothing, New IntPtr(exstyle)))
                End If
                SetWindowPos(New HandleRef(Me, Me.Handle), New HandleRef(Nothing, New IntPtr(HWND_TOPMOST)), 0, 0, 0, 0, (SWP_DRAWFRAME Or SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE))
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            Finally
                MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
            End Try
        End Sub

        <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLong", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
        Friend Shared Function GetWindowLong32(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Int32
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLongPtr", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
        Friend Shared Function GetWindowLong64(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Int64
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
        Friend Shared Function SetWindowLong32(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As HandleRef) As Int32
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLongPtr", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
        Friend Shared Function SetWindowLong64(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As HandleRef) As Int64
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
        Friend Shared Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As HandleRef, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal flags As Integer) As Boolean
        End Function

        Friend Const GWL_EXSTYLE As Integer = -20
        Friend Const GWL_STYLE As Integer = -16
        Friend Const HWND_TOPMOST As Integer = -1
        Friend Const SWP_DRAWFRAME As Integer = &H20
        Friend Const SWP_NOMOVE As Integer = 2
        Friend Const SWP_NOSIZE As Integer = 1
        Friend Const SWP_NOZORDER As Integer = 4
        Friend Const SWP_NOOWNERZORDER As Integer = &H200
        Friend Const WS_CAPTION As Integer = &HC00000
        Friend Const WS_THICKFRAME As Integer = &H40000
        Friend Const WS_MAXIMIZE As Integer = &H1000000
        Friend Const WS_MINIMIZE As Integer = &H20000000
        Friend Const WS_SYSMENU As Integer = &H80000
        Friend Const WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME As Integer = 1
        Friend Const WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE As Integer = &H200
        Friend Const WS_EX_STATICEDGE As Integer = &H20000

    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: What is the use for a form that is 1x1 pixel?  What is the overall goal that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway The window is initialized with a much bigger size. But it needs to support (re-)sizing. All the way down to `0x0`.

Comment: couldn't you just set a `.TransparencyKey`?

Comment: @porkchop Nope. Setting the transparency key will not affect the size of the window.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå i know; i was just wondering why you need to make the window zero size to begin with. so a quick hack might do, unless you have some specific purpose, of which i cannot possibly be aware. in any case, carry on.

Comment: Resizing a window to zero prevents it ever being resizable again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum size of a window is normally restricted to the smallest size that still allows the system menu and the caption buttons to be accessible by the user.  Even for borderless windows, not exactly appropriate.  You can make it smaller by explicitly setting the Size property *after* the window is created, normally the Load event handler is your first opportunity.  Or OnHandleCreated().

But yeah, Windows still restricts it to 2x2, the "why" is elusive.  Surely what you *really* want to know is how to work around it.  You do so by intercepting the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message and lowering the minimum track size.  A sample form class that demonstrates the approach:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
        If m.Msg = WM_GETMINMAXINFO Then
            Dim mmi = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(MINMAXINFO)), MINMAXINFO)
            mmi.ptMinTrackSize = New Point(0, 0)
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(mmi, m.LParam, False)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Size = New Size(0, 0)
        MsgBox(Me.Size.ToString())
    End Sub

    Private Const WM_GETMINMAXINFO As Integer = &h24
    Private Structure MINMAXINFO
        Public ptReserved As Point
        Public ptMaxSize As Point
        Public ptMaxPosition As Point
        Public ptMinTrackSize As Point
        Public ptMaxTrackSize As Point
    End Structure
End Class
```

Tested on Windows 8.1.  I can't promise that it will work on all Windows versions.  It should.